# SSRS - How can I link to a deployed report that uses a reportviewer? How do I get the url to link to report?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

Can you please advise me of where I can locate reportviewer url's like the following example...

```
<a href="http://<Server>/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fMyApp%2fCustom+Reports%2fMyReport&rs:Command=Render"
```

The situation is, I want to deploy a report but after I deploy it to the server where will I get the url or how can I construct it so that I can point my application to the correct report.

I have been trying to track down some previously deployed reports to see if I can work out the url but I cannot find anything.

Comment: How are you running the deployed reports now? The URL will be in the browser address textbox when you run the report.

Comment: Hi, within Reporting Services\ReportServer\Pages there is an aspx page containing a ReportViewer ie ReportViewer.aspx that is being used to render the reports. This relates to the url above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That report isn't using the nice "Report Manager" web interface, it is effectively a back-end method for accessing the reports. It is mostly used for programmatically accessing reports via URL generation for parameters and other things.

For more information about the syntax of the URL parameters and how to use them see the following MSDN pages:

- [URL Access (SSRS)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms153586.aspx)
- [URL Access Parameter Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152835.aspx)
- [Pass a Report Parameter Within a URL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155391.aspx)

If you're just trying to view reports online you might want to use `http://server/Reports/` which will load the proper Report Manager interface which is how you would normally manage and view deployed reports.

Comment: Yes, I know it's not using the report manager, its using a reportviewer control within a .aspx page. But the question I am asking is if I deploy a report, how can I understand what the url to that report will be?

Comment: Then the links I gave about the syntax of the web service URLs should be helpful.

Comment: Thanks mike, these have been useful.